# Call SOAP web service with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, web-services, soap

I am looking for a code sample to see if we can call the SOAP web service directly from AngularJS service like we call RESTful APIs. I dont want to use third party plugins.

Currently I am using the `HttpWebrequest`

```
    using (var requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
    {

        if (fileData != null)
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        }

        return webrequest.GetResponse();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.